# Differentiating row vector vs column vector when deriving the Hessian

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, hessian-matrix

Consider the one-layer neural network $y=\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x} +b$ and the optimization objective $J(\mathbf{w}) = \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac12 (1-y\cdot t) \right]$ where $t\in\{-1,1\}$ is the label of our data point. I am asked to compute the Hessian of $J$ at the current location $\mathbf{w}$ in the parameter space. I know that the correct solution is $H=\frac{\partial^2J}{\partial \mathbf{w}^2} = \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T \right]$.

I am having issues to arrive at this exact formulation because of how derivation of row/column vectors work. My solution goes as follows:
We first determine the first derivative.

\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac12 \left( 1 - yt \right)^2 \right]}{\partial \mathbf{w}}\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\partial \frac12 \left( 1 - yt \right)^2 }{\partial \mathbf{w}} \right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\partial \frac12 \left( 1 - yt \right)^2 }{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{w}} \right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ -t\cdot(1-yt) \frac{\partial \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}+b}{\partial \mathbf{w}} \right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ -t\cdot(1-yt) \mathbf{x} \right]\\
\end{align*}

Note that I think $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ is considered a *column* vector, and according to the matrix cookbook, $ \frac{\partial \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}+b}{\partial \mathbf{w}} = \mathbf{x}$, not $\mathbf{x}^T$ (I have found sources saying otherwise...)

We now differentiate this again, in order to derive the Hessian.
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[ -t\cdot(1-yt) \mathbf{x} \right]}{\partial \mathbf{w}}\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\partial -t(1-yt)\mathbf{x}}{\partial y}  \frac{\partial \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}+b}{\partial \mathbf{w}} \right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\partial -t(1-yt)\mathbf{x}}{\partial y}  \mathbf{x} \right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\partial (-t+yt^2)\mathbf{x}}{\partial y}  \mathbf{x} \right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \underbrace{t^2}_{= 1} \mathbf{x}  \mathbf{x} \right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{x}  \mathbf{x} \right]\\
&\neq \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T \right]
\end{align*}

So here, we have column vector times column vector which is not really defined. I do not know where to get the transpose from, though. I tried deriving the whole thing again with the assumption that $\frac{\partial \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}+b}{\partial \mathbf{w}} = \mathbf{x}^T$, instead of $\mathbf{x}$. Then we either get $\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}^T \right]$ similar to before, or, *if* we assume that the derivative of a row vector w.r.t. scalar is a column vector, we get $\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T \right]$, which is what we want. However,this would be a very weird assumption, to me, because why would the derivative of a row vector w.r.t. to a scalar be a column vector? And furthermore, it contradicts the matrix cookbook, which says that  $\frac{\partial \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}+b}{\partial \mathbf{w}} = \mathbf{x}$.

I would be very glad for help here. Where did I go wrong? Which assumptions of row/column vectors are correct? Thank you so much for your help!

Last, I found an alternative way of solving it where you don't have that issue of transposing or not, by just inserting the definition of the prediction $y$, but I still would like to know where the issue in my solution above lies.

\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[ -t\cdot(1-yt) \mathbf{x} \right]}{\partial \mathbf{w}}\\
&= \frac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[ -t\mathbf{x} + t^2y\mathbf{x} \right]}{\partial \mathbf{w}}\\
&= \frac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[ -t\mathbf{x} + t^2(w^T\mathbf{x} + b)\mathbf{x} \right]}{\partial \mathbf{w}}\\
&= \frac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[ -t\mathbf{x} + t^2(w^T\mathbf{x})\mathbf{x} + b\mathbf{x} \right]}{\partial \mathbf{w}}\\
&= \frac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[ -t\mathbf{x} + t^2\mathbf{x}^Tw\mathbf{x} + b\mathbf{x} \right]}{\partial \mathbf{w}}\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \underbrace{t^2}_{= 1} \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T \right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T \right]\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Forgetting the expectation operator (for a while),
the differential of the cost function writes
$$
d\phi
= t(t\cdot y-1)dy
= (y-t) \mathbf{x}^Td\mathbf{w}
$$
since $dy=\mathbf{x}^Td\mathbf{w}$.

The gradient is $\mathbf{g}
=
(y-t) \mathbf{x}
$

It follows that
$d\mathbf{g}
=
dy\cdot \mathbf{x}
=
(\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T) d\mathbf{w}
$
which gives the Hessian $\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! TBH, I have not worked a lot with multidimensional calculus, and usually solve these tasks like outlined in my question. In your answer, I don't really follow the argumentation flow (i.e., how do you get $dy=x^Tdw$ if we don't even have something like $d/dw$ - I don't understand the notation here). In any case, this seems like a different approach to solve the question. I would like to know where I did go wrong in my derivation, to understand how to get the transpose in my solution back...

Comment: I think your error comes from the way you have applied the chain rule. You should have a look here [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus] to understand the difference between numerator and denominator layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is "the correct way of doing it." Nor are either wrong. There are two conventions, and as long as you follow the same convention consistently, you will get sensible answers.

If you treat the derivative as a linear operator approximating your function, then the derivative of a function $\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^m$ is a linear function $\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^m$. In the case that $m = 1$, that gives you a row vector.

Now let's start:

\begin{align}
   D_w (w^Tx + b)^2 &= 2(w^Tx + b)x^T \\
   H_w (w^Tx + b)^2 &= D_w [2(w^Tx + b)x^T]
\end{align}

Row vectors, right? But now stop right there! The function $f(w) = 2(w^Tx + b)x^T$ is a function from $\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$ **even if** the output is a row vector. More precisely, we want to pick a basis (the dual basis) for the space of row vectors and calculate our derivative in that basis. Representing a row vector in the dual basis is just taking the transpose, so we get

$$
H_w (w^Tx + b)^2 = D_w [2(w^Tx + b)x] = 2x D_w (w^Tx) = 2xx^T
$$

where we use the rule $D_x cf(x) = c D_x f(x)$.

---

This is how I think about the Hessian. As the second derivative where we need to compute each derivative in the appropriate basis and that means taking the transpose on the second step. I learned to think about it this way studying differential geometry/topology.

Sources that don't want to discuss derivatives on manifolds, might simply define $H(f) = D(\nabla f)$ (the derivative/Jacobian of the gradient). Where by definition $\nabla f = (D f)^T$.

When you do it via basis to basis. Every map from $\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^m$ is the same type of thing. If you aren't considering bases, then you need to worry about row vectors and column vectors and there become 4 kinds of maps $\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^m$ (row to row, row to column, etc.). Then you need a consistent way of computing those derivatives.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried following it as best as I could (e.g., I'm not too sure what a "linear operator approximating a function" is - I'm sorry...). I understand that your statement is that as long as we treat row/column vectors consistently, we will get correct results. 

However, first a question to your example. You say the function $f(w)$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ even if the output is a row vector. But would that be $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ instead? I thought $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just short for column vector.

Comment: Second, I don't really understand your notation of the Hessian $H_w(...)^2$. What does the square mean and how did you get there, starting at $\frac12(1-yt)$ in my initial question? 

And third, I still don't understand where I introduced some inconsistency in my solution that I outlined in my question. There must be an issue because I don't arrive at the correct solution, but the alternative approaches don't help me in seeing the issue.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for your help and I am really sorry for my limited knowledge here. I'm kinda new to all of this...

Comment: @Maxbit When we write $f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a)(x - a)$ and $x - a$ is a vector, then $f'(a)$ is a thing that can be multiplied to the left of a vector. Normally this is some kind of matrix, if $x - a$ is a column vector. If $x - a$ is a row vector then it might be more naturally written as $(x - a)f'(a)$. But we can define a function $T$ such that $T(x) = xA$ from row-vectors to row vectors. This is the kind of *thing* that $f'(a)$ is. Second, I should probably say that $f$ and not $f(w)$ is a function from $\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$. So $w$ is a vector and $f(w)$ is another vector.

Comment: Next, the square is the same square that you have in your problem: $(1 - yt)^2$. But I changed the function to $(w^Tx + b)^2$ to isolate the general form of the expression we are differentiating. $D_w$ is the derivative, $H_w$ is the second derivative/Hessian. I was trying to explain that to me, $H_w = D_w^2$ (take the derivative, then take the derivative again). But to do so, you need to pay attention to the kind of derivative being taken. That's why on Wikipedia you see $H_w = D_w\nabla_w$ (derivative of the gradient where the gradient is the transposed derivative).

Comment: And this is because there must be some different convention for taking the derivative of row-valued functions versus column valued. For instance, in the formula $D_w(cf) = cD_w(f)$. That depends on what sort of constant you have—$f$ is scalar-valued. Because it could either be $D_w(cf) = c D_w(f)$ or $D_w(f) c$. Because now it matters which side gets the $c$. So when I have $D_w[(w^T x) x] = xw^T$, I am putting the $x$ to the left and not the right as in $w^Tx$. And you need to think carefully of why this is so.

Comment: You put the $x$ on the right, which was wrong, and for the derivative, you actually took the gradient $x$ rather and not the derivative $x^T$. So it should have been $x \cdot \text{derivative}$ where the derivative is $x^T$ not $x$.